# where is installed file located on android phones

Tags: android, location, external, apk

Hi Friends i want to know where the installed file is located on android phones.
Dear i cannot find that files on my cell.

I am using samsung galaxys2 .

Any one tried storing the data in textfile and that file i want to see on my cell after i run my code on my cell instead of emulator im running my code through my cell.

Im sorry for bad english.

```
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub


         if(windowOpen == false)    {
        Connection con = null;
        java.sql.Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setTitle("Delete Sub_Category :");
        f.setSize(600,200);

        model = new DefaultTableModel(datas,titles);
        table = new JTable(model);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);     
        f.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        JButton deleteButton = new JButton("Delete");
        JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
        f.getContentPane().add(panel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel.add(deleteButton);
        panel.add(cancelButton);
```

I am sorry this is not my code i could not able to send my question soo i posted like this.
Help me please
         Thanks in advance

Comment: Epic fail.. The question is too cryptic for me.. :D . You might wanna see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuation

Answer (score 0):

Starting form API Level 8, you can allow your application to be installed on the external storage i.e., the device's SD card.This is an optional feature in which you can declare for your application with the **android:installLocation** manifest attribute.

If you do not declare this attribute, your application will be installed on the internal storage only and it cannot be moved to the external storage.The internal location is /data/app/yourapplicationsname.

Also i have a link where i suppose you can easily solve your problem.the link is as follows:-[Important Link for your question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3002/where-in-the-file-system-are-applications-installed/)